# Git - Trying to change a previous commit message leads to a wrong commit

Tags: git, commit, history

I want to change a message of a commit that is not pushed. Therefore I am using the command

```
 git rebase -i "commitId".
```

However, when I execute this command, it doesn't lead to the commit message I want to edit. Perhaps it shows the messages of my other commits. Went something wrong so the match to the right commit is not working anymore? Example:

commit **cad487486b6465dff38b25392673ba23024fe615** (HEAD -> master)
Author: Kaan Cayoglu
Date:   Mon Nov 27 13:04:44 2017 +0100

```
LPM-406 - Send encryption certificates to stand-in
```

commit **788ae89a51779a07be3b3266a22cef750298bcea**
Author: Kaan Cayoglu
Date:   Mon Nov 27 13:03:34 2017 +0100

```
LPM-405 - Renewal of softtoken
```

commit **8bca40e4c9b933e7bcc9b430d72d97fb309eeba5**
Author: Kaan Cayoglu
Date:   Mon Nov 27 12:56:47 2017 +0100

```
LPM-396 Replace softtoken process
```

So let's say I want to edit the message of *8bca40e4c9b933e7bcc9b430d72d97fb309eeba5*. I am using the command git rebase -i "*8bca40e4c9b933e7bcc9b430d72d97fb309eeba5*". The vi editor opens but there I see the message of the other both commits but not the one I want to see. Any ideas..?

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `rebase` is the new base commit, so you want `commitId^` as the argument. `^` denotes the parent of the specified commit.

Comment: Not precisely right, though. The argument is the "upstream", which defines where rebase stops looking for commits to process (and which *by default* also serves as the new base onto which the commits are rewritten -- but see `--onto`).  So the advice is ok with the caveats that it can be a mess if this traverses any merges, and that sometimes `commitId^` isn't valid because `commitId` has no parent (in which case you replace `commitId^` with `--root`).

Answer (score 1):

The command your using is interactive rebasing `git rebase -i` this can be used to change the message, but if you just want to change the message of the last commit it is easier to do:

```
git commit --amend -m "New message"
```

Note that this will change the commit date and the message, and therefore the SHA-256 key of the commit, so its a bad idea to do this on published commits.

Comment: I see.. But I didn't want to change my last commit anyway